# IOTA testnet setup

Tags: testnet

I am trying to setup an IOTA dev environment (see https://iota.readme.io). I am connecting to a testnode (http://p101.iotaledger.net) using Javascript library. The connection works. I can create a new address (always the same) and can check the balance. However, I am not sure, if this setup really is coorect, balance is 0 I have no test tokens yet.

**Question:** Do I need to run locally the testnet iri additionally to connecting to the remote node? 
e.g. like this: starting the IRI.
`java -jar iri-1.4.1.2.jar -n udp://sandboxes.community:7474`
and parallel access the above mentioned testnode? Or should I connect to the local iri and use the -n upd://*:* to talk to the testnode?
This is confusing because I read that a node should have if not a static IP at least a domain. I want to use this for IoT and those devices won't have a static IPs of course.